# Codeigniter system folder error

Tags: codeigniter, runtime-error, message

I am working on a project with codeigniter and all of a sudden I started getting this kind of error message. 
And it is coming from the system folder, database driver, language.

Here is the error message

```
A Database Error occurred
Error Number 1364
Field 'english' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO 'language' ('Phrase') VALUES ('Question')

Filename C:\Wamp64\www\sms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number : 330
```

Answer (score 0):

Your language table has English column, there is you have not set the default value and you are trying to insert in language table without English column value.

That's it.

Thanks